# Linux Samba/Winbind - groups not refreshing when using SSH - Active Directory membership

Tags: active-directory, samba

We have Linux hosts that are bound to our Active Directory Domain user Samba/Winbind to be a member server - for users to get access to the servers we use a domain group placed into the sshd_config. So user gets added to group and then in theory they can login - that was the plan.

At the moment we can add a user to the group - and if that group has never been used before the server will reach out and grab the group membership. But once that has been done the group membership does not refresh - without going to the extremes of removing tdb files and rebinding the machine to the domain which is a mess.

Has anyone ever got around this problem?

What is annoying is that if I ssh onto the box - add a user to the AD group then 'su' to the user the groups are refreshed. However that does not work if you 'sudo su' (I don't want people's passwords)

```
workgroup = INTERNAL
realm = INTERNAL.NETWORK
netbios name = no1
security = ADS
dns forwarder = { 123.123.123.123; 123.123.123.123 }
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config *:range = 50000-1000000
template homedir = /home/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
winbind use default domain = true
winbind nss info = rfc2307
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind use nested groups = yes
pam password change = yes
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
encrypt passwords = true

winbind cache time = 10
```

I am wondering if the issue is SSH looking at the group and this does not trigger an event to go and check the group membership in AD?

Can get around this with using local groups and domain users - but this is annoying that surely this is something that fundamentally should work

Thanks

Comment: What version of Linux and Samba/WinBind are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your smb.conf is borked or you are using sssd, if the latter, this has nothing to do with Samba, if the former, please read this:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member

Comment: Moved away from using sssd back to this - I'll have a read through that article and see if there is something I have entered wrong in the smb.conf - perhaps there is a bad entry in the file